# AngularJS directive - link function element param not availble in watch function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

I'm trying to do something very simple:

I defined a directive ('A' type) that need to manipulate the element when the scope property changed.

**JS**

```
 app.directive("autoAnimation", function ()
        {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    animateChanged: '=',
                    maxHeight: '@'//for the first time
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs)
                    {
                        var isFirstTime = true;
                        scope.$watch('animateChanged', function (newVal)
                        {
                          console.log(newVal)

                                   //Trying to get the 'element' but it's not available - what can I do to get the ul element and manipulate it?
                                    //why it's not available?

                        });

                    }
            };
        });
```

**HTML**

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model='isChecked' />
   <ul auto-animation animate-changed='isChecked'>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
   </ul>

  </body>
```

The problem is when the 'animateChanged' is changed, the 'element' (and scope) parameter are not available.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/33HLaEK7F1nuMc6usx7y?p=preview).

**My questions:**

1) why it's not available?
2) what can I do to manipulate the 'ul' element (where the directive is declared - see the HTML) when 'animateChanged' is changed?

**EDIT**

I didn't check the example, and in this example it's available (my bad, sorry).
 but in my project it's not available, and I can't bring the example to my situation... (in my project the UL build dynamically with ng-repeat).
Any idea what can possibly cause to this behavior?

Comment: looks fine to me http://plnkr.co/edit/D2MfkqkMEUp5EgibIHDV?p=preview

Comment: You are right!! but it's available in my project, I dont know why..

Answer (score 0):

They are available, just change the inside of your watch to console.log(newVal, element, scope):

```
console.log(newVal, element, scope)
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/NZq6G04zsVBg2GgNWZkv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

As you are `$watch`ing in a link function so that *(element)* is available, change to this:

```
console.log(element);
```

actually `console.log(newVal)` was outputting the state of the clicked element so when `checked:true/unchecked:false`.

Comment: You are right!! but it's available in my project (this is just a test) maybe other things in my project cause to this problem...

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? do you want to perform something when checkbox gets checked/unchecked like show/hide?